# Translate nlohmann into json to torch tensor

Tags: c++, templates, pytorch, nlohmann-json

I have this code with specific hard-coded dimension and dimensionality

```
  auto x_data=json_data.at("x").get<std::vector<std::vector<float>>>();
  auto x_options = torch::TensorOptions().dtype(at::kFloat);
  torch::Tensor x_tensor = torch::zeros({32,10}, x_options); 
  int x_n=32;
  int x_m=10;
  for (int i = 0; i < x_n; i++)
    x_tensor.slice(0, i,i+1) = torch::from_blob(x_data[i].data(), {x_m}, x_options);

  auto y_data=json_data.at("y").get<std::vector<float>>();
  auto y_opts =torch::TensorOptions().dtype(at::kFloat);
  torch::Tensor y_tensor = torch::from_blob(y_data.data(), {54},y_opts);
```

I want a really generic that I can use like this

```
torch::Tensor x_tensor=getTensorFromJson<float>(json_data);
torch::Tensor y_tensor=getTensorFromJson<float>(json_data);
```

What modern c++ technique will you use for implementing it?
No need to put the code, I just need some hints for starting study.

PS I want to be flexible also for n D vector with n>2.
Thank you.

Comment: You should take a look at: https://json.nlohmann.me/features/arbitrary_types/